# Try to use Stylus in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, stylus

I am trying to install and use [Stylus](https://github.com/forgecrafted/ruby-stylus) in a brand new rails app.

First, I've created a new rails app: `rails new try-stylus`

Then, I've run the command: `sudo npm install stylus`

And, I've added `gem 'stylus'` to my `Gemfile`, and run `bundle` to install it.

In `application.rb` at the end of `Application < Rails::Application` class, I've added:

```
if defined? 
   Stylus.debug = Rails.env != "production"
end
```

I've renamed `application.css` to `application.styl` and edit its content:

```
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

body
  background red
```

I've created a simple `PageController` with an `index` action rendering an Hello world template `index.html.erb`.

Eventually, I've run `rails s`.

And got the following error in my browser:

> Showing /.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>   ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
>   TypeError: undefined is not a function

Where line 5 is:
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Do you have any clue?